# Is it correct to say that bidirectional file declarations do not set flags implicitly?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, stream, fstream

This statement [here](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibug/30-3.html) doesn't seem to be correct:

> Bidirectional file streams, on the other hand, do not have the flag
>   set implicitly. This is because a              bidirectional stream
>   does not have to be in both input and output mode in all cases. You
>   might want to open a bidirectional stream for reading only or writing
>   only. Bidirectional file streams therefore have no implicit input or
>   output mode. You must always set a bidirectional file stream's open
>   mode explicitly.

otherwise, this code wouldn't compile.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream file("novo.txt", ios::out);
    char i;
    file >> i;
}
```

Comment: I just overlooked that, but what compiler are you using? Some compilers have "extensions" that could make a illegal code compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there has [historically been some confusion regarding this matter](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/13081/), I believe the statement you quoted is indeed misleading, but not for the reason in your example. Bidirectional file streams do set the flag implicitly, as noted in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4dx08bh4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
void open(
const char *_Filename,
ios_base::openmode _Mode = ios_base::in | ios_base::out,
int _Prot = (int)ios_base::_Openprot
);
```

Based on the Apache statement, I would NOT expect your code sample to fail, as it explicitly sets the flag to ::out. I would, on the other hand, expect this code to fail:

```
int main()
{
    fstream file("novo.txt");
    char i;
    file >> i;
}
```

But based on the MSDN documentation, this code will not fail either, and the file will default to ios_base::in & out (and, hence, the Apache statement is not entirely accurate).

Comment: How did you conclude this : "Based on the Apache statement, I would NOT expect your code sample to fail, as it explicitly sets the flag to ::out ?"

Comment: According to Apache, "You must always set a bidirectional file stream's open mode explicitly" which is exactly what you did by including the ios::out parameter.

Comment: But in this case `file >> i;` would fail.

Answer (score 2):

## Statement is true for gcc

> This statement here doesn't seem to be correct: […]

I don't know about standards, or Visual Studio, but I know about the C++ I'm using, which is the one from GCC. There you can have a look at [the relevant header](http://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/fstream;hb=0c8766b14373cdc13b9c966130ec877e0fa29865).

[`oistream::open`](http://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/fstream;hb=0c8766b14373cdc13b9c966130ec877e0fa29865#l539) looks like this:

```
inline void
istream::open(const char* __s, ios_base::openmode __mode = ios_base::in) {
  if (!_M_filebuf.open(__s, __mode | ios_base::in))
```

So you have two things here: a *default* function argument in case you didn't specify one when calling the method, and a *forced* flag which is always or-ed into the provided mode. So no matter what mode you specify, input mode will always be added to your specification. Other code, the constructor in particular, will delegate to this. A similar situation occurs with [`ofstream::open`](http://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libstdc%2b%2b-v3/include/std/fstream;hb=0c8766b14373cdc13b9c966130ec877e0fa29865#l714). On the other hand, [`fstream::open`](http://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=libstdc%2b%2b-v3/include/std/fstream;hb=0c8766b14373cdc13b9c966130ec877e0fa29865#l887) has the *default* argument, but no *forced* argument:

```
inline void
fstream::open(const char* __s,
              ios_base::openmode __mode = ios_base::in | ios_base::out) {
  if (!_M_filebuf.open(__s, __mode))
```

As a consequence, not passing any mode is all right (at least in this implementation, but read the answer by @kmote for more details on this), but *if* you do pass any mode, *then* you must pass either `in` or `out` or both as well, as there will be no forced mode added to the modes you specify (or fail to specify).

This is the way I read the Apache documentation, and the sources support my view, at least for my implementation. As all of this is in templated code, you can look at the headers from a different compiler to see how it handles these situations. So have a look at the VS headers, look for `basic_fstream` and see how its methods are implemented.

## Lack of compiler error

> otherwise, this code wouldn't compile.

Your code opens a bidirectional stream for output only, and then attempts to input things from it. There is no reason why this should fail to *compile*. The static type of the stream is `fstream`, i.e. bidirectional. Only at runtime, you are passing a certain flag with a certain meaning to the constructor. The compiler (usually) won't check for that, so your code will therefore misbehave at runtime, when it fails to actually read from the stream.

Note that I'm not sure whether Windows actually supports opening a file for output only. It *might* well be that the only file modes supported by the OS are read-only and read-write. (Note that I'm just speculating here.) In that case, opening a file for output only and reading from it afterwards would not be a problem even at runtime, as there would be no difference between opening a file with `out` only or with `in|out`. For the sake of portability, the correct mode should be chosen, as there are kernels out there which support write-only files.

Comment: I agree with you. The compiler should not complain in this case as the class fstream has the operator>>().